# Some questions on the Archimidean property in Abbott (2015).

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have had no formal training in analysis before, and am using *Understanding Analysis* by Abbott (2015) for self-study.

My questions concern his presentation of the *Archimedean property*, and I would appreciate if members of the community could supply me with the tacit context I am clearly missing here.

**Context.**

The statement of the theorem he uses is as follows:

> **Theorem 1.4.2** (Archimidean Property).
>
> (i) Given any number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satsifying $n > x$.
>
> (ii) Given any real number $y > 0$  there exists and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $1 /n < y$.

The author then goes on to state that

> Part $(i)$ of the proposition [in Theorem 1.4.2] states that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

His proof by contradiction of part $(i)$ of Theorem 1.4.2 states that

> Assume for contradiction that $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above,. By the axiom of completeness (AoC), $\mathbb{N}$ should have a least upper bound, and we can set $\alpha = \sup \mathbb{N}$. If we consider $\alpha - 1$ then we no longer have an upper bound, (see Lemma 1.3.8) and therefore there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $\alpha - 1 < n.$

Where his statement of the axiom of completeness is

> **Axiom of Completeness.** Every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

And the lemma he references is

> **Lemma 1.3.8.**. Assume $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for the set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then $s = \sup A$ if and only if for every choice of $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element $a \in A$ satisfying $s - \epsilon < a$.

**Queries.**

1. *Why does part $(i)$ of Theorem 1.4.2 mean that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above?*

I unable to see this intutively or formally. Intuitively, I parse part $(i)$ of Theorem 1.4.2 as "for any given real number we can always find a natural number that is bigger than said real number." Formally, Abbott's definition of an upper bound is stated in terms of $\mathbb{R}$. His definition is

> **Definition 1.3.1.** A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is *bounded above* if there exists a $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq b$ for all $a \in A$. The number $b$ is an *upper bound* for $A$.

Using this definition I cannot see how $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above, nor do I understand how his definition can be applied to $\mathbb{N}$, given that it is stated in terms of $\mathbb{R}$.

2. *Given that Abbott's statement of the AoC and Lemma 1.3.8 are couched in terms of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{N}$, what step is he relying on to justify the applications of both to the extract of the proof of contradiction I have included?*

Whilst I understand that he has assumed that $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above to show that yields a contradiction, I fail to see how he can invoke his statement of AoC, given that it is an axiom about real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, not natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, and similarly with Lemma 1.3.8, which is also a statement couched in terms of $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: From the context of your post it looks like you may have missed an important aspect of the author's presentation, namely where $\mathbb N$ is presented as a subset of $\mathbb R$. Once you know that, you can then apply Definition 1.3.1 using $A = \mathbb N$. Does that help?

Comment: @Lee Mosher. Yes that is immensely helpful, thank you. I had a niggling feeling that it was to do with the fact that I was drawing an inappropriate distinction between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$, when in fact $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$, but I couldn't be sure. That clearly resolves question 2, and the subsequent answer has resolved my question 1.

Comment: @Lee Mosher. If you don't mind, I have converted your comment into an answer. If that is a problem do say, otherwise I will assume it is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb N$ were bounded above it would mean that we could find a *real* number that is larger than (or equal to) each natural. Then, to say that $\mathbb N$ is *not* bounded above is to say that we *cannot* find such a real number -- or in other words, that no matter which real number we pick, the number we picked is *not* one that is larger than (or equal to) each of the naturals.

But 1.4.2(i) says exactly that no matter which element of $\mathbb R$ you pick, there is a larger natural. This means that the real was not larger than that particular natural, and therefore especially it fails to be larger than *all* the naturals.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is answered clearly by [Troposphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/907303/troposphere), above.

Your second query has been equally clearly settled by [Lee Mosher](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26501/lee-mosher) in the comments. Converting his comment into an answer,

> From the context of your post it looks like you may have missed an important aspect of the author's presentation, namely where $\mathbb{N}$ is presented as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Once you know that, you can then apply Definition 1.3.1 using $A = \mathbb{N}$.